# Problems with scaling meshes. Unwrapping transforms the scale back to normal

Tags: mesh, uv

I've been stuck the past hours by trying to scale my mesh. In object mode the mesh i use is perfectly scaled but once i go into the editor it seems that the mesh won't really scale. I have attached two pictures illustrating my problem:

[image]

[image]

As shown in picture 2, the mesh is scaling but once i unwrap it, the mesh is scaled back to its normal (as shown in picture 1).

Does anyone of you know how my mesh can be scaled as intended after the unwrapping has been made?

Help would be much appreciated :-)!

Comment: Use unwrap from view (bounds), so that the UV map is constrained to the edges of the image.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Could you be a little more specific of where i use the "unwrap" from view (bounds)?

Im kinda new to blender :-)....

Comment: Please add the information to the question, not in the comments.

Comment: Exactly. So can you help me with scaling the mesh permanently after the unwrapping? I want to make a light map of the mesh, but once i click "lightmap pack" on my scaled mesh (picture 2) it jumps back to picture 1? –

Comment: See the [edit] link at the bottom of your question? Please use it.

Comment: if you want to scale the UV map then scale it the way you want, why are you unwrapping it again? of course it will go back to the default unwrapped UV map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that UV unwrapping transforms the scale. It just discards previous UV mapping and creates a new one for selected faces. And it tries to take as much texture as possible (if it won't cause stretching), so in your case it just puts 4 corners of a square face on 4 corners of a square texture. I don't know why you keep unwrapping the mesh after scaling it, but either way you should consider using **scale** vector of a **mapping** node:

[image]